# Create a executable java maven project

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven

I have created a project using Maven. The main idea is to get the dependencies easily. The problem is that now I can't create an executable .exe or even a .jar file. My application is a Java archetype and I'm doing it with Netbeans. Also I'm using an Postgree db. My pom file shown bellow:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.metrum</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtuapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-alpha</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>unknown-jars-temp-repo</id>
            <name>A temporary repository created by NetBeans for libraries and jars it could not identify. Please replace the dependencies in this repository with correct ones and delete this repository.</name>
            <url>file:${project.basedir}/lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.balloontip</groupId>
            <artifactId>balloontip</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx-beaninfo</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
            <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

I fact I want to create a installer to my app.

---Edit---

I tried to use `maven-jar-plugin` to create and executable jar file as suggested. My new pom file is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.metrum</groupId>
    <artifactId>mtuapp</artifactId>
    <version>0.1-alpha</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>com.metrum.mtuapp.main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.4-1201-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.java.balloontip</groupId>
            <artifactId>balloontip</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.swinglabs.swingx</groupId>
            <artifactId>swingx-beaninfo</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.scream3r</groupId>
            <artifactId>jssc</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

</project>
```

With this I'm getting:

```
java -jar mtuapp-0.1-alpha.jar


Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/c
ontext/annotation/AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
        at com.metrum.mtuapp.main.Main.<clinit>(Main.java:20)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.context.annotat
ion.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see that your project is created using maven so your jar file is created in the target folder in the `root` directory of your project, you just need to execute the goal `mvn clean package` to generate it, but this is not going to be an executable jar file.

If you want to create an installer and create a .exe file you need to use another tool I recommend you to use http://www.jrsoftware.org/isdl.php you can find the documentation [here](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) .

----edits----

If you want to create an executable jar you have to add a plugin into your pom file with the next lines:

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- Build an executable JAR -->
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.4</version>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
            <mainClass>com.mypackage.MyClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

check the complete information [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/)

If you want to include the maven dependencies you can use the  **maven-assembly-plugin**

```
<plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <archive>
          <manifest>
            <mainClass>fully.qualified.MainClass</mainClass>
          </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
          <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: When I try to run the jar file with java -jar it returns that it doesn't have any attribute in the main manifest...do you know what it means?

Comment: It means that your jar file is not executable, If you want to create an executable jar file you need to use a maven plugin check the maven-jar-plugin for this purpose

Comment: could you give me some directions to search about it?

Comment: Great, now it's generating an executable jar file. On the other hand, it seems that the jar do not include dependencies.

Comment: I tried to put 
    <descriptorRefs>
        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
    </descriptorRefs>
and it still returns classnotfoundexception to spring annotation

Comment: Check my edits in the answer it is going to create two jars use the jar with dependencies here is the complete documentation https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81316/discussion-between-leandro-and-alejandro-agapito-bautista).

Comment: do I need to put both the plugin in the pom?
I put the jar plugin and the assembly and I'm still receiving the same error..